# A method in java application .Which method should return data from Rest Api

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have an application in JavaFX and spring boot. Another web application in spring boot. From web application, I can access Fx application through rest API. But now  I want to call a method in java Fx application. Which method return data as String from the web application.How can I do this?

```
 public  String getCustomerData(){

/* RestUrl Of web application */
    String url="http://192.168.012.106:8080/restrole/customer/get/1?access_token=e91ad118-141a6026b954";

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("HeaderName", "value");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    HttpEntity<Customers> request = new HttpEntity<>(Customers, headers);

    restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, Customers.class);

    /* here I want to catch the JSON data and return it.*/
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected ResponseEntity<AllCustomerTypeMessage> getCustomerData(String token) {
    try {

        String url = "http://192.168.012.106:8080/restrole/customer/get?access_token=" + token;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<AllCustomerTypeMessage> allCustomerType = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(headers), AllCustomerTypeMessage.class);


        return allCustomerType;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    return null;
}
```